# Not able to access private protect member in iterator php

Tags: php, iterator

Here is the data Iterator implementation

```
//Data Iterator 
    class DataIterator implements Iterator
    {
        public $data ;
        public function __construct(Data $obj)
        {
            $this->data = $obj;
        }
        public function rewind()
        {
            $this->properties = get_object_vars($this->data);                       
        }
        public function valid()
        {
            if (key($this->properties) === null )
            {
                return false;
            }   
            return true;
        }
        public function key()
        {
            return key($this->properties);
        }
        public function current()
        {
             return current($this->properties);
        }
        public function next()
        {
            next($this->properties);
        }

    }
```

and here is data class

```
 /*Data Class*/
    class Data implements IteratorAggregate
    {
        public $name; 
        private $age;
        protected $address;
        public $country;
        public $state;

        public function __construct($name, $age, $address, $country = 'USA', $state = 'NH')
        {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->address = $address;
            $this->country = $country;
            $this->state = $state;
        }
        function getIterator()
        {       
            return new DataIterator($this);
        }
    }
```

And here is the calling part

```
$data = new Data('Joker', '27', 'California');

    foreach($data->getIterator() as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key , ' ', $value, '<br>';
    }
```

output

```
name Joker
country USA
state NH
```

Notice that the output does not contain my private and protected properties (age, address) output.

How do I tell Iterator to output those as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell the iterator to output those properties because they are simply not accessible from the outside (i.e. the point where the iterator does `get_object_vars($this->data)`.

There are two ways you could go about doing this:

1. By having the data object pass the values to the iterator.
2. Use the reflection API to pull them out by force (verbose, slow!).

But before going ahead with #1 as the preferred option, stop for a moment and ask yourself: **why does the iterator expose non-public members of the data object?**

Making something `private` means "You people don't really need to know about this; it may go away in the future, or it may change beyond recognition". If it's something that the outside world cares about, then why is it not `public` (either directly, or exposed through a public getter)? A rethink of what this iterator's purpose is might be in order.

That said, here's how you would do #1:

```
class DataIterator implements Iterator
{
    public $data;
    private $properties;
    public function __construct(Data $obj, array $propeties)
    {
        $this->data = $obj;
        $this->properties = $properties;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        // Arguably horrible trick to refresh the property map without
        // demanding that Data exposes a separate API just for this purpose
        $newIterator = $this->data->getIterator();
        $this->properties = $newIterator->properties;
    }
}

class Data implements IteratorAggregate
{
    function getIterator()
    {       
        return new DataIterator($this, get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Public, private and protected are access modifiers. They are designed to restrict the accessibility of your class attributes.

- **Public** means that any one can access that attribute, so if someone wants, they can change the value, without that you know it.
- **Private** mean that the attribute is only accessible INSIDE the class,
  so nobody can "mess" with those properties from OUTSIDE the class.
- **Protected** is similar like Private, but child classes (classes that
  inherit from that class) have access to it.

You are making `age` and `address` private, so you are basically saying, nobody is allowed to access these attributes. If you want to access private/protected attributes, you will have to make getters and setters and call these functions, or make the attributes public.

Answer (score 0):

try get_class_vars

```
$this->properties = get_class_vars(get_class($this->data));
```

instead of
    $this->properties = get_object_vars($this->data);